# Does Nuxt Bridge migration upgrade to Vue 3 as well?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt-bridge

I recently updated our app to use Nuxt Bridge following this guide:
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/bridge/overview

We were previously on Vue `2.7.10` but now when I check my vue version using `npm view vue version` I get `3.2.39`.
But If I go into node_modules/vue/package.json I see this:

```
  "name": "vue",
  "version": "2.7.10",
```

I tried deleting node_modules, yarn.lock, .nuxt and explicitly added `"vue":"3.2.39"` to package.json then redid yarn install. After that I got an error about nuxt `Cannot find module 'nuxt'`.

So I guess my questions are: How can I tell which version of Vue I'm actually using in this project?
My goal is to upgrade to Vue 3, is there an issue with Nuxt Bridge and Vue 3?

Comment: Hm, if I'm not mistaken Nuxt Bridge is still based on Vue2 and it brings some Composition API capabilities. Faster way would probably be to simply upgrade towards Nuxt3.

Comment: @kissu Thank you for confirming what I thought about Nuxt Bridge, although I wasn't finding documentation on it yesterday. Unfortunately we can't upgrade to Nuxt3 yet since it isn't stable for production.

Comment: Depends on your needs, can totally be fine on production.